# Select an item once in a combobox

Tags: powershell, combobox, selecteditem

So, I have a weird problem where I select an item from my combobox list, and in order to populate a second combobox, I must first select the word AGAIN from the first one - not from the list of items, rather the word itself. Only then will the code register that I have selected that Item. The code that I have is the simple $variable.SelectedItem. See code below;

```
$ComboBox_Location.Add_Click{

switch ($ComboBox_Location.SelectedItem){

    "Hospital"{
        $ComboBox_Printer.Items.Clear();
        foreach($Name in $Hospital){
        $ComboBox_Printer.Items.Add("$($Name.name)");
        }
```

All I want to do is select the location "Hospital" from the pulldown list, then the second ComboBox named "$ComboBox_Printer" populates with names of printers from my server.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably due to the `Add_Click` event you're using. You will have more success with an event handler like `Add_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: Perfect. I have been changing the "selecteditem" instead of looking where the click event actually was happening. Thank you Nas. Now, on a similar note (or maybe a new question), why is it pulling duplicate printer names on my print server?

Comment: If it's unrelated to this question or proposed solution you should create a new one.

Comment: Agreed, create a new question and show the current result, expected result and the code that is generating the current result. Could be something as simple as not clearing a list or grabbing the list twice. I know from experience that the index change has some problems with doubling up actions.